# If a sequence is decreasing to zero, why do we have the following

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be some real sequence and let $S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{|i|<n}^n|a_i|$. I need to verify two claims.

First, if $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, why $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}S_n=2\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_i|=0$$

Second, it is claimed that by the dominated convergence theorem
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{|i|<n}\left(1 - \frac{|i|}{n}\right)a_i = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}a_i$$

Could you help me, please to see why this is the case, why do we need the dominated convergence theorem and what is the dominating sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, assuming $a_n\to 0$ as $|n|\to \infty$, note that $$\frac{S_n}{n}\le \frac{2\max_{i\in \{-n,\cdots,n\}}|a_i|}{n}\le \frac{2M}{n}$$ where $M$ is upper bound on $\{|a_n|\}$, which exists since $\{a_n\}$ converges. So, $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n/n=2\lim_
{n\to \infty}|a_i|=0$.

Comment: Why should $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ imply that $\sup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} |a_i| < \infty$?

Comment: @GenericNickname, this is because, as $a_n\to 0$, $\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists N$ such that $|a_n|<\epsilon\ \forall n\ge N$.

Comment: Yes. But it does not prevent $a_n \to \infty$ for $n \to -\infty$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, @GenericNickname, you are correct. I think for the result in the question to hold true, we need $a_n\to 0$ as $|n|\to \infty$. Otherwise,  we could have $\sup_{i\in \{-n,\cdots,n\}}|a_n|>\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n's$.